# Titanium - Separate views in 'touchmove' animation

Tags: titanium

I am try to do appointment in a dayView in a calander I have build. But when I try to animate one appointment with 'longpress' and 'touchmove' the other appointments goes with, I try to use 'this.' but stil have problem.
Sorry that I hace comment the code on swedish :)
I would Appreciate if some one helped me!

Here is my code..

```
Ti.include('globalization/sv-SE.js');
Ti.include('core.js');

Ti.include('parser.js');
Ti.include('sugarpak.js');
Ti.include('time.js');

var time = 1;

var myTime = null;

var rows = [];

//Skapa fönstret med vit bakgrund
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor : 'white'
});

var calanderHeader = Ti.UI.createView({
    width : '100%',
    height : '50dp'
});

win.add(calanderHeader);

//Skapa en scrollView till dag-kalenderna
var dayViewScroll = Titanium.UI.createScrollView({
    top : '80dp',
    //  canCancelEvents: false,
    disableBounce : true,
    contentHeight : 'auto',
    backgroundColor : '#00ff00',

});

//Skapa själva kalendern
var dayViewCalenderContent = Ti.UI.createView({
    layout : 'vertical',
    height : '1464dp'
});

//Lägger kalenderna i scrollView
dayViewScroll.add(dayViewCalenderContent);

//Lägger scrollView till fönstret
win.add(dayViewScroll);

//Skapa alla 24 timmarna
for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {

    //Se till att alla timmarna
    //är 2 sifriga.
    if (time < 10) {
        myTime = '0' + time + '.00';
    } else {
        myTime = time + '.00';
    }

    //Skapa linjerna till timm-raderna.
    var hr = Ti.UI.createView({
        width : '100%',
        height : '1dp',
        backgroundColor : '#bbb',
        top : '0dp',
        bottom : '0dp'
    });

    rows.push(hr);

    //Skapa timm-raderna.
    var myRow = Ti.UI.createView({
        backgroundColor : 'white',
        borderColor : '#bbb',
        borderWidth : '0dp',
        width : '100%',
        height : '60dp',
        top : '0dp',
        left : '0dp'

    });

    //Skapa högra linjen av timmarna
    var borderRight = Ti.UI.createView({
        height : '100%',
        width : '1dp',
        backgroundColor : '#bbb',
        top : '0dp',
        left : '90dp',
        bottom : '0dp'
    });

    myRow.add(borderRight);

    myRow.index = i;

    //Skapa halvtimmers linjerna
    var timeLine = Ti.UI.createView({
        width : '100%',
        height : '1dp',
        backgroundColor : '#bbb',
        left : '91dp',
        top : '30dp'
    });

    myRow.add(timeLine);

    var timeRow = Ti.UI.createView({
        backgroundColor : 'white',
        borderColor : '#bbb',
        borderWidth : '0dp',
        width : '90dp',
        height : '60dp',
        top : '0dp',
        left : '0dp'
    });

    myRow.add(timeRow);

    //Skapa siffrona i timmarna.
    var timeLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        left : '25dp',
        top : '23dp',
        text : myTime

    });

    //Lägg till siffrona till timm-kolumnen.
    timeRow.add(timeLabel);

    myRow.foo = myTime;

    rows.push(myRow);

    time++;

}

//Lägg till alla skapta timmarna till kalenderna
dayViewCalenderContent.add(rows);

function Createbooking(globalPoint, bookedfromHaur, bookedfromMinute, bookedToHaur, bookedToMinute) {

    var globalPoint = globalPoint;

    var bookedfromHaur = bookedfromHaur;

    var bookedfromMinute = bookedfromMinute;

    var bookedToHaur = bookedToHaur;

    var bookedToMinute = bookedToMinute;

    // this.top = globalPoint;

    //Skapa bokningsobjektet.
    var bookingView = Titanium.UI.createView({
        backgroundColor : '#000',
        width : '160dp',
        height : '92dp',
        bubbleParent : false,
        top : globalPoint
    });

    // this.bookingView.top = globalPoint;

    //Skapa vyn för timmarna i bokningsobjektet
    var bookingTimeView = Titanium.UI.createView({
        backgroundColor : '#000',
        height : 32,
        width : '60%',
        bubbleParent : false,
        top : 0

    });

    bookingView.add(bookingTimeView);

    bookingView.myBookingStartTime = new Date();

    bookingView.myBookingEndTime = new Date();

    bookingView.myBookedFrom = bookingView.myBookingStartTime.set({
        hour : bookedfromHaur,
        minute : bookedfromMinute
    }).toString('HH:mm');

    bookingView.myBookedTo = bookingView.myBookingEndTime.set({
        hour : bookedToHaur,
        minute : bookedToMinute
    }).toString('HH:mm');

    // var myDay = (11:mm).addHours(6);

    //Skapa boka-från tidssiffrona.
    bookingView.myBookingFromTimeLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        color : '#FFFFFF',
        left : '0dp',
        top : '3dp',
        text : bookingView.myBookedFrom

    });

    //Skapa mellanslag mellan bokade tiderna
    myBookingSeparaterTimeLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        color : '#FFFFFF',
        top : '3dp',
        text : ' -- '

    });

    //Skapa boka-till tidssiffrona.
    bookingView.myBookingToTimeLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        color : '#FFFFFF',
        top : '3dp',
        right : '0dp',
        text : bookingView.myBookedTo

    });

    //Lägg till bokningstids siffrona till Vyn för boknings tiderna
    bookingTimeView.add(bookingView.myBookingFromTimeLabel);
    bookingTimeView.add(myBookingSeparaterTimeLabel);
    bookingTimeView.add(bookingView.myBookingToTimeLabel);

    //Skapa boknings objektets body
    var bookingViewContent = Titanium.UI.createView({
        backgroundColor : 'yellow',
        width : '160dp',
        top : '32dp',
        bottom : '32dp'
    });

    //Lägg till body i bokningsobjektet.
    bookingView.add(bookingViewContent);

    //Skapa handtaget till bokningsobjektet.
    var dragDownView = Ti.UI.createView({
        width : '160dp',
        height : '32dp',
        bottom : '0dp',
        backgroundColor : '#999',
        zIndex : 20
    });

    //Lägg till handtaget till bokningsobjektet.
    bookingView.add(dragDownView);

    //Skapa bild-Vy till handtaget.
    dragDownImageView = Ti.UI.createView({
        width : '70dp',
        height : '32dp',
        left : '95dp',
        bottom : '0dp',
        backgroundImage : 'images/dragDownIco.png',
        zIndex : 20
    });

    //Lägg till bilden till handtaget.
    dragDownView.add(dragDownImageView);

    //Skapa "lysnare" till 'touchstart' på kalenderna
    dayViewScroll.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {

        //stoppa scrollningen vid 'touchstart'.
        dayViewScroll.setScrollingEnabled(false);

        // alert(e);

    });

    //Skapa "lysnare" till 'touchmove' på kalenderna
    dayViewScroll.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {

        this.myFinalGlobal = e.source.index * 61 + e.y + 1;

        var newBookingEndTime = new Date();

        var newBookedEndTime = newBookingEndTime.set({
            hour : 12,
            minute : 0
        }).addMinutes(6).toString('HH:mm');

        // updateEndTime(newBookedEndTime);

        bookingView.myBookingToTimeLabel.setText(newBookedEndTime);

        bookedToHaur = 10;

        // alert(globalPoint);

        if (this.myFinalGlobal - bookingView.top) {

            bookingView.animate({
                height : this.myFinalGlobal - bookingView.top,
                duration : 10
            });

            bookingView.setHeight(this.myFinalGlobal - bookingView.top);

        }

    });

    dayViewScroll.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {

        bookingView.setHeight(globalPoint + e.y);

        dayViewScroll.setScrollingEnabled(true);

        alert(bookingView.getHeight);

    });

    bookingView.setHeight(this.myFinalGlobal - bookingView.top);

    return bookingView;

}

Createbooking.prototype.myToushMove = function() {

    alert(this.globalPoint);

};

//Skapa 'lysnare' till 'longpress'.
dayViewCalenderContent.addEventListener('longpress', function(e) {

    var myGlobal = e.source.index * 61 + e.y + 1;

    var bookedfromHaur = e.source.index + 1;

    var bookedfromMinute = e.y;

    var bookedToHaur = e.source.index + 1;

    var bookedToMinute = e.y;

    this.myBooking = new Createbooking(myGlobal, bookedfromHaur, bookedfromMinute, bookedToHaur, bookedToMinute);

    // e.source._event_myStart = myBooking;

    dayViewScroll.add(this.myBooking);

    //dayViewScroll.addEventListener('touchmove', myMove);

    function myMove(e) {

        //alert('Hejsan');

        var myBookedFinalTo = this.myBooking.myBookingEndTime.set({
            hour : bookedToHaur,
            minute : bookedToMinute
        }).addMinutes(e.y).toString('HH:mm');

        this.myBooking.myBookingToTimeLabel.setText(myBookedFinalTo);

        var myFinalGlobal = e.source.index * 61 + e.y + 1;

        if (myFinalGlobal > this.myBooking.top) {

            this.myBooking.animate({
                height : myFinalGlobal - this.myBooking.top,
                duration : 10
            });

            this.myBooking.setHeight(myFinalGlobal - this.myBooking.top);

            //alert(myFinalGlobal - myBooking.top);

        }

    }

});

win.open();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "this." on an event handler. That'll have undesirable consequences, like your code not working, and it has a performance hit too (due to crossing from JS to Native when writing, and back when reading). Instead, promote some variables out to the appropriate scope.

Right now, you're doing:

```
function bar() {
    this.foo++;
}
```

Instead do:

```
var foo = 0;
function bar() {
    foo++;
}
```